# Multilist datasource query that filters only items where a field contains the ID of the item being edited

Tags: templates

Here's the scenario.  We have a list of FAQs and each FAQ can be assigned to one or more categories.  This is done via a Multiselect in the FAQ item template.

But we are now redesigning our FAQ landing page such that we are displaying a grid of FAQ categories and each category shows the FAQs that have been assigned to that category, but at least on the intial landing page, only a few FAQs show up, and we want to give the ability to select which FAQs those would be.

So, my initial thought was to create a multiselect in the FAQ Category item template.  But to do so, I would want to have only FAQ items show up that have been assigned to that category.  Is that possible?  Is there a way to create a query that will work in a mulilist that grabs the current FAQ Category ID and compares that with the ID of the FAQ Category Multiselect field in the FAQ Items that are in the search, or is this really beyond what queries support at this time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not able to achieve this in a multilist with out-of-box features. 
The query for your requirement should be like this `query:/sitecore/content/FAQ/*[contains(@FAQCategory, 'Current-FAQ-Category-ID')]` but unfortunately you can't build like this in source field of a multilist, because there is no way to pass your "Current FAQ Category ID" in the multilist source query to compare with category ids selected in FAQ items.

Note - You can extend Multilist/Multilist with search field and create your own custom field to achieve this.